# GKE Limit RAM & CPU

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Am using GKE(google managed kubernetes) and I have requirement where I want to leave around 10% of memory on each Node as Idle so that during burst workload scenarios, the pod's already deployed on that Node can make use of those idle resources (within limit range)

Basically What I want to achieve is, I want to avoid a scenario where Pod's get scheduled onto a Node till 100% resources are consumed and assuming all the Pod's/Services are utilizing their allocated resources (set via requests) and one of the POD has a burst workload scenario or the pod got restarted and it needs more memory during boot up, then it should be able to make use of those idle resources

After going through the documentation I have come across this, but since GKE is a managed service, these properties aren't exposed anywhere, are there any other ways to achieve the same ?

[image]

Comment: You will be set limits on CPU & memory for your pods
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-memory-resource/

Set limits for pods such that is leaves 10% as buffer.  I think GKE does expose CPU target utilisation, not sure if the same option is present for memory usage

Comment: let me explain with an example, am setting both limits & Requests, say for example , on a 8 Core 24GB Ram machine, for each Node am spawning 8 Pods where for each Pod, requests is set to 700m and 2GB memory and limit is set to 1000m & 6GB memory, so with 8 pods, resource utilization will be 5.6 CPU & 16GB memory, rest of the 8GB memory and 2.4 CPU, I want to leave idle so that existing Pods can use for the above mentioned scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GKE is a managed service and therefore you will not be able to costumize the worker node kublet parameters like --eviction-hard or --system-reserved.

As a workaround, you need to calculate your pod's memory requests and memory limits in order to [configure a maximum number of pods per node](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr#configuring_maximum_pods_per_node), in this way you can controle the number of pods that run on your node and the spare CPU and memory to be used by your pods in case of a burst.

Comment: the problem with configuring max number of pods per Node is, cluster IP range gets decided based on this setting and basis this the no of Nodes that can be added to the cluster will be very low, for example if I set max_pods per node to 8, then max no of Nodes that can be added to cluster will be 128 and I might require more no of Nodes than this in future

Comment: You can add additional [node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools) to the same cluster when needed.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misunderstood Cluster IP address range with that of Nodes IP address range and we can in fact have more no of Nodes added to the cluster compared to that of default max_pods_per node configuration. And since this is a Node-Pool level setting, we should create a new Node pool with this setting... this should solve the problem instead of maxing out CPU or RAM to ensure only N no of Pods are landed on a Node and GKE also exposed this property to override at the time of cluster creation